# Keep the image fixed height css

Tags: html, css

I have been scratching my head over it for a long time. Unable to find a solution. I have uploaded the website on live server for you to see. Ok the problem is that logo keeps pushing the div down causing navigation menu to break . The problem is worse on firefox and safari.

It would be hard to explain unless you see it yourself however I am attaching an image to make it clear what the problem is.

[image]

Here is the URL where page is located: [bitcoinirl.ie](http://bitcoinirl.ie)

P.S: I know it is a bad practice to post url instead of code but really can't figure out the cause for the problem. Hence unable to paste appropriate code

Ahmar

Comment: It's not the logo that pushes down the menu..each of .nav-menu__link is 120px width, so it doesn't fit your screen..

Comment: Is that because you didn't write the code? Why can't you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I see countless problems in the code (or is it template/boilerplate?), this fixes the problem as you describe it, without accounting for your lesser screen sizes (I can't test the fix because the menu gets garbled on responsive breaks).

Line 334 or so of styles.css

```
.nav-menu__link {
    width: 120px; // Change this to 12-13% instead of 120px;
}
```